# OpenGL ES 1.1 2D (iPhone): Resizing a group of textures/rectangular objects

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I'm trying to resize whats being displayed by OpneGL ES on the screen by a factor equally.

More clearly, i'm trying to resize a layer by a factor, so that all the objects associated with that layer are resized by that factor.

-Suppose i have 2 images:image_1 of size:100x100 and image_2 of size:50x50. Both in layer_1.

-I set the layer_1 size to 0.5.

-The image_1 and image_2 should resize to 50x50 and 25x25 respectively.

-The images should be drawn in a new resized position.

I've been able to achieve this effect by doing some calculations on the CPU.
I would like to know if there is a way to do it on the GPU. Something like drawing to an empty texture. Is it possible with OpenGL ES 1.1? I'm quite new to OpenGL and graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to calculate the scale on the GPU. So you will have to do calculations on the CPU as far as I know.

For the most part with OpenGL the drawing is handled with the GPU while most calculations are handled with the CPU.

Comment: True but is it possible to draw to a texture and resize that texture to achieve that effect? I don't know about drawing to a texture yet.